# How to change the color of the cell dynamically after the ui grid is loaded

Tags: angularjs, ui-grid

Searched Stack Overflow and Google a lot but cannot understand how to change the background color of a cell in ui grid after the grid is loaded with values.

For example after a button press I want to change background color on the cell.

Comment: Please provide some code, what did you try :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use Rowtemplate and override ui-grid-cell. In the rowTemplate, you can add ng-click function and do whatever you want to do inside that function.

One more option to add an html for cellTemplate and add ng-class, based on conditions update class and have css for that class accordingly.